# how to save multi image in hasmany eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel

I have product and images models. Both have images column.
Product has parent image, images have child images.

My update code is:

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request){
       $validatedData = $request->validate([  
            'image' => 'required',
        ]); 
        $image = Input::file('image'); 
        if (isset($image))
        { 
            foreach($request->image as $image){ 
                $directory = public_path().'/uploads/programs';
                if(!file_exists($directory)) File::makeDirectory($directory,0777, true, true);
                $filename  = sha1(time().time()).".png";    
                $filename  = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename  = str_random(40)."$filename";
                $upload_success = $image->move($directory, $filename);
                $input['image'] = $filename;  
            } 
        }
```

How can I update images in both at a time?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [ 
        'image' => 'required|array',
    ]); 
   $oProduct = Product::create([
    //insert data for product table
    )];

   $oProduct->images()->saveMany(collect($request->image)>map(function($image) 
  {
        return new Image([
            'image' => $image
        ]);
    }));

}

Here images() is hasMany relation with Product so that relationship access for 
this.
```